# Bootstrap - need of "col-sm-12"?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

simple question - is `<div class="col-sm-12">` needed?

Example 1:

```
<div class="row">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        half
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        half
    </div>
</div>
```

Example 2:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        half
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        half
    </div>
</div>
```

What is better and why?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All bootstrap grids works as your second example. `.row` element have a negative margin to compensate the positive padding in the `.col-*` elements. So it´s better and more logical your second example.

In the first example, you haven't got the paddings of the `.col-*` elements and the negative margin will produce unexpected results.

### Example with `col-sm-12`:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        half
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        half
    </div>
</div>
```

### Example without `col-sm-12`:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        half
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        half
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, in the second example you'll obtain a negative margin in the `<h1>` element. That's why you must use columns always into the rows.

Comment: How come the `float` isn't applied to the columns?

Comment: External bootstrap library throws a Permission Denied error, but you can test it in your localhost. I will try to fix this error in the snippet, but the problem is clear. :)

Comment: Yea, I know it works - upvoted already :) however, I'm not getting any network error in the console (chrome v50), so I thought that maybe in v3.3.6 they changed something in the grid. Tnx for the update :)

Comment: It's possible, I don't know why this doesn't works. LOL. I edited without protocol because it throws errors, but now doesn't throws errors but still doesn't works. However, all people can test it in a boostrap fiddle like this: http://www.bootply.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll suggest you use the following way:

```
<h1>title</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        half
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        half
    </div>
</div>
```

In this way, we don't need to worry about -ve `margin` issue or some other layout problem. Its a good rule that bootstrap grid columns should be only direct children of `.row`